# Java - menu loop and math calculations

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that will give the user a menu, allow them to select an option, then ask for different numbers to do a calculation based on their menu choice. I've started with the basic outline of the program, but I need help getting loops implemented and working.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LB04Alexander {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("This program will perform several types of calculations.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("-MENU-");
    System.out.println("Select from the following menu options:");
    System.out.println("1 - Compute integer powers of a number");
    System.out.println("2 - Compute a factorial");
    System.out.println("3 - Compute a square root");
    System.out.println("4 - Compute a cube root");
    System.out.println("5 - Compute an exponential");
    System.out.println("6 - Compute the sine of an angle");
    System.out.println("7 - Compute the cosine of an angle");
    System.out.println("8 - Convert a positive integer to binary");
    System.out.println("9 - Exit");
    System.out.println("Please enter the number corresponding to your choice:");

    int menuChoice = input.nextInt();
    while (menuChoice >= 1 && menuChoice <= 9); {
        switch (menuChoice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You have chosen to compute integer powers of a number.");
            System.out.println("Please enter any number for the base:");
            double base1 = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Now, enter a non-negative integer for the exponent:");
            int exponent1 = input.nextInt();
            if (exponent1 < 0)
                System.out.println("Error: exponent is negitive.");
            else
                System.out.println(base1 + "^" + exponent1 + " = " + "");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("You have chosen to compute a factorial (n!) of a non-negative integer.");
            System.out.println("Please enter a non-negitive integer for n:");
            long fact = input.nextLong();
            int result = 1; 
            if (fact < 0) 
                System.out.println("Error: integer is negitive.");
            else if (fact >= 127)
                System.out.println("Error: Answer too large to calculate");
            else
                for (int i = 1; i <= fact; i++) {
                    result = result * i;
                }
            System.out.println(fact + "! = " + result );
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("You have chosen to compute a square root.");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("You have chosen to compute a cube root.");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("You have chosen to compute an exponential.");   
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("You have chosen to compute the sine of an angle."); 
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("You have chosen to compute the cosine of an angle.");   
            break;
        case 8:
            System.out.println("You have chosen to convert a positive integer to binary");  
            break;
        case 9:
            System.out.println("You have chosen to exit");
            System.out.println("Program LB04Alexander is now terminating...");
            input.close();
            System.out.println("The program has ended. Goodbye.");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid menu choice, please try again.");
            break;

        } }


}
}
```

The first problem I'm having is getting the menu to loop the right way. it either doesn't work, or loops forever.

Comment: currently, the program accepts a number, but does nothing. If I change the while loop to a do-while, with `while (menuChoice >= 1 && menuChoice <= 9);` at the end, if works, but loops only the chosen case over and over again.

Answer (score 3):

```
while (menuChoice >= 1 && menuChoice <= 9);
```

Get rid of that semi-colon. When your choice satisfies the condition, it loops forever. When it doesn't, it will quit immediately <s>(since none of the cases match)</s> after printing out `Invalid menu choice, please try again.`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Whoops, skimmed OP's code too quickly and didn't even see the default choice.

Comment: I took out the semi-colon which helped. Once a calculation is successful, I want the program to direct back to the main menu

Comment: You *could* break to a label but that's kind of ugly. A better way would be to organize your code differently. Perhaps each "menu" could be its own method called from `main`. When a user elects to return to the previous menu, you just return from the method.

Comment: How would i go about doing that? Sorry, I've just started learning.

Comment: @Gregory It's a lot to explain. I'd suggest starting small first and figuring out the basic "pieces" of the language: flow-control (conditionals and looping), methods, class/objects, etc. and how they fit together. The general idea is that for each of your sub-menus, you will call another method that mimics what you're doing in main (has a `while` loop). If they choose to return from the menu, you simply return from the method itself (exit the `while`) loop and then return from the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is somewhat more modular than yours but about the same ...

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class LB04Alexander {

      public static final Scanner SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;

        showMenu();
        while((choice = getInt("Please enter the number corresponding to your choice:")) != 9) {
          doCalculation(choice);
          showMenu();
        }
      }

      public static void showMenu() {
        System.out.println("This program will preform several types on calculations.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("===============MENU=====================");
        System.out.println("Select from the following menu options:");
        System.out.println("1 - Compute integer powers of a number");
        System.out.println("2 - Compute a factorial");
        System.out.println("3 - Compute a square root");
        System.out.println("4 - Compute a cube root");
        System.out.println("5 - Compute an exponential");
        System.out.println("6 - Compute the sine of an angle");
        System.out.println("7 - Compute the cosine of an angle");
        System.out.println("8 - Convert a positive integer to binary");
        System.out.println("9 - Exit");
        System.out.println("========================================");

      }


      private static void doCalculation(int choice) {
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
          System.out.println("\nYou have chosen to compute integer powers of a number.");
          double base1 = getDouble("Please enter the number corresponding to your choice:");
          int exponent1 = getInt("Now, enter a non-negative integer for the exponent:");
          System.out.println(base1 + "^" + exponent1 + " = " + "");
          break;
        case 2:
          System.out.println("You have chosen to compute a factorial (n!) of a non-negative integer.");
          long fact = getLong("Please enter a non-negitive integer for n:");
          int result = 1;
          if (fact < 0)
            System.out.println("Error: integer is negitive.");
          else if (fact >= 127)
            System.out.println("Error: Answer too large to calculate");
          else
            for (int i = 1; i <= fact; i++) {
              result = result * i;
            }
          System.out.println(fact + "! = " + result );
          break;
        case 3:
          System.out.println("You have chosen to compute a square root.");
          break;
        case 4:
          System.out.println("You have chosen to compute a cube root.");
          break;
        case 5:
          System.out.println("You have chosen to compute an exponential.");
          break;
        case 6:
          System.out.println("You have chosen to compute the sine of an angle.");
          break;
        case 7:
          System.out.println("You have chosen to compute the cosine of an angle.");
          break;
        case 8:
          System.out.println("You have chosen to convert a positive integer to binary");
          break;
        default:
          System.out.println("Invalid menu choice, please try again.");
          break;
        }
      }

      private static int getInt(String prompt) {
        boolean unassigned = true;
        int value = 0;
        while(unassigned) {
          try {
              System.out.println(prompt);
              value = SCANNER.nextInt();
              unassigned = false;
          }
          catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
        }
          System.out.println("[" + value + "]");

        return value;
      }

      private static double getDouble(String prompt) {
        boolean unassigned = true;
        double value = 0;
        while(unassigned) {
          try {
              System.out.println(prompt);
              value = SCANNER.nextDouble();
              unassigned = false;
          }
          catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
        }
          System.out.println("[" + value + "]");
        return value;
      }

      private static long getLong(String prompt) {
        boolean unassigned = true;
        long value = 0;
        while(unassigned) {
          try {
              System.out.println(prompt);
              value = SCANNER.nextLong();
              unassigned = false;
          }
          catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
        }
          System.out.println("[" + value + "]");

        return value;
      }
    }
```